# Restricting checkbox selection to a subset w/out using functions in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to restrict the number of records that may be selected in a list to a subset of the total records by disabling the remaining records once the max is reached. The list may be 1000s of records in length so performance is an issue. I'm worried my current solution (below/[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALPEP/)) will not scale. I've read several articles that warn against using functions (**maxSelected()** in this case) in **ng-repeat** for performance reasons, but not sure how I can accomplish this without them? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here's the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ALPEP/

HTML:

```html
<div ng-controller="recordsCollectionController">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        ng-repeat="record in records"
        ng-class="{info:selected[record.id], warning:!selected[record.id] && maxSelected()}">
        <td>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            ng-model="selected[record.id]"
            ng-disabled="!selected[record.id] && maxSelected()"
            id="{{record.id}}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="{{record.id}}">{{record.name}}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
angular
  .module('App',[])
  .controller('recordsCollectionController',function($scope){
    $scope.selected = {"1":true,"2":true,"3":true};
    $scope.records = [
      {"id":1,"name":"Homer"},
      {"id":2,"name":"Marge"},
      {"id":3,"name":"Bart"},
      {"id":4,"name":"Lisa"},
      {"id":5,"name":"Maggie"}
    ];
    $scope.maxSelected = function(){
      var count = 0;
      for(x in $scope.selected){
        if($scope.selected[x]) count++;
      }
      return (count===3) ? true : false;
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option. Your original code had 2*N^2 compares per $digest. This has N compares per selection change. The basic change is to track the selected count and update it via ng-change, rather than counting it again every time it's needed.

```
<div ng-controller="recordsCollectionController">
    <pre>selected = {{selected}}</pre>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:20px"/>
            <col/>
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr
                ng-repeat="record in records"
                ng-class="{info:selected[record.id], warning:!selected[record.id] && selMax}">
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        ng-model="selected[record.id]"
                        ng-disabled="!selected[record.id] && selMax"
                        ng-change="updateSelected()"
                        id="{{record.id}}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="{{record.id}}">
                        {{record.name}}
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

angular
    .module('App',[])
    .controller('recordsCollectionController',function($scope){
        $scope.selected = {"1":true,"2":true,"3":true};
        $scope.selMax = true;
        $scope.records = [
            {"id":1,"name":"Homer"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Marge"},
            {"id":3,"name":"Bart"},
            {"id":4,"name":"Lisa"},
            {"id":5,"name":"Maggie"}
        ];

        $scope.updateSelected = function(){
            console.log("Ping!");
            var count = 0;
            for(x in $scope.selected){
                if($scope.selected[x]) count++;
            }
            $scope.selMax = (count >= 3);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Actually I don't see a point in iterating and counting when you could have done `$scope.selMax++` and place the `count >= 3` in your `ng-disabled`

Comment: I considered skipping the iteration entirely and just incrementing or decrementing a count when selection changed, but it felt potentially fragile if the two got out of sync. Of course, that's dwarfed by the larger problem of what happens to your selection model when the record list is changed.